# How to gracefully disconnect from rabbitmq queue

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, windows-services

I am experiencing a racing condition issue with my rabbitmq client. My service has multiple instances listening on a single queue, storing received messages into a db.

When they all get restarted at once, i sometimes see messages being redelivered and stored in the db twice. This is normally handled on client side by checking if the correlationid has already been stored in the db. This works 99.9% of the time (i am processing 5mill messages a day, it happens once or twice a day).

So as i said, i suspect a racing condition being responsible for this. I think i receive the message again while my first message is still being processed. So when i check i dont see it stored in the db, and in the end, store it twice.

I should not that this is a non-issue, but has been bothering me because i can't really explain what happens.

I suspect that it happens when i restart the services. I think i disconnect from the queue, while i am still processing the message, triggering rabbitmq to redeliver again to another instance that is not shutdown yet.

What i want to do is when i am stopping the service is to

- tell rabbitmq that i dont want to receive further messages
- wait for all currently processing messages to finish
- send acks / nacks
- shutdown

Right now i am first deregistering the received event

```
_consumerServer.Received -= MessageReceived;
```

then i am disposing the channel and the server

```
        if (_channel != null)
        {
            _channel.Close();
            _channel.Dispose();
        }

        if (_connectionServer != null)
        {
            _connectionServer.Close();
            _connectionServer.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: What about using a distributed lock system like ZooKeeper?

Comment: I am not familiar with ZooKeeper, but i will take a look

Comment: I think you have to implement that manually, by using some thread synchronization constructs (like `Monitor.Wait\Pulse`) to ensure that all processing in `MessageReceived` is finished before shutdown. Alternatively just not allow inserting duplicates to database (either via unique index or via careful sql query).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try and shut down a consumer so that messages won't be redelivered, you should handle redelivery correctly. Check for and handle the case where the `redelivered` flag is set on a message, and act appropriately. You should also try store your messages in such a way that the store operation is idempotent - i.e. it can happen multiple times and you will only have one record in your database.

Please see the guidelines that the team have provided here:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html#consumer